# How can I allow imports into my webworker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-worker

I have some basic code here.

https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-nightingale-80r4ps?file=/src/App.js:24-332

`App.js`: I create a webworker, and I have a function to post a message to that worker. When I receive a message back, I run `console.log(e.data);`.

```
export default function App() {
  const worker = new Worker("Worker.js");

  worker.onmessage = (e) => {
    console.log(e.data);
  };

  function getCount() {
    worker.postMessage("get count");
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={getCount}>Get count!</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`Worker.js`: Inside the worker, I create a `counter` object and post a message with its value.

```
class counter {
  constructor() {
    this.value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  }
}

onmessage = (e) => {
  const myCounter = new counter();
  this.postMessage(myCounter.value);
};
```

I would like to import the below helper functions and classes into my webworker, instead of embedding them in the file directly. Is there a way to do this if my worker is located in `public`?

My file structure is like this:

```
root
-src
--utility1
--class1
-public
--webworker
```

Comment: What do you want to import?

Comment: For instance, a class or utility function. They are currently located in my src file.

Comment: Have you tried to export and import these functions, instances or classes? The worker has to have `type: 'module'`.

Comment: I have, and I get this error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at SolveWorker.js:1:1)`

Comment: Have you set `type: 'module'`? Does your browser support module workers? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Worker#browser_compatibility

Comment: My browser supports it, but as many do not, I would prefer not to use the type setting upon creation of the worker- is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Workers can have type `classic` or `module`. Workers with type `module` support ES6 modules.

Example:
`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Module Worker Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`index.js`

```
const worker = new Worker('Worker.js', { type: 'module' });

worker.onmessage = (e) => {
  console.log(e.data);
};

function getCount() {
  worker.postMessage('get count');
}

getCount();
```

`Worker.js`

```
import { Counter } from './Counter.js';

onmessage = (e) => {
  const myCounter = new Counter();
  postMessage(myCounter.value);
};
```

`Counter.js`

```
export class Counter {
  constructor() {
    this.value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  }
}
```

Currently, it's not supported by all major browsers.

An alternative option is a worker with type `classic` and `importScripts`:

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Module Worker Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`index.js`

```
const worker = new Worker('Worker.js');

worker.onmessage = (e) => {
  console.log(e.data);
};

function getCount() {
  worker.postMessage('get count');
}

getCount();
```

`Worker.js`

```
importScripts('./Counter.js');

onmessage = (e) => {
  const myCounter = new Counter();
  postMessage(myCounter.value);
};
```

`Counter.js`

```
class Counter {
  constructor() {
    this.value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  }
}
```

It works on all major browsers.

Comment: Thanks. Since it's not supported by all major browsers, it seems that I would need to embed it. If I do so, would I need to manually minify the worker as it resides in `public`? Furthermore, is using `importScripts` a viable option instead?

Comment: @713sean Minification is always optional. A correct minifier doesn't change the behavior. I don't know [`importScripts`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts), but it looks like an alternative option.

Comment: @713sean I've tested `importScripts` with a classic worker. It seems to work and is supported by all major browsers. I added it to my answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks- sorry to be a pain but this doesn't work for me. I get `'importScripts' is not defined.eslintno-undef`, both on my codesandbox and on a React project I made myself.

Comment: @713sean That's your linter ESLint. You can ignore that line or try to configure it.